# Hiding LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linkbutton

In VB.NET, I have a `LinkButton` that, when clicked, creates a report.  We want to disable this functionality based on whom is logged into the system.  I have a session variable to indicate whether this should be visible or not but when I set `idLinkButton.visible = False`, it has no effect.  Any ideas on what I need to do to be able to turn this on and off?

'code-behind
' in page_load
If Not Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session("HideReports")) Then
        PDFbutton.Visible = True
Else If Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session("HideReports")) And   HttpContext.Current.Session("LoadFromConsole") Then
        PDFbutton.Visible = True
end if

Comment: I take it this is ASP.NET then - tag added.

Comment: Can you please provide the code showing the LinkButton and the code-behind itself. Looks like it might be the order that you are performing the actions.

Comment: First the property is `.Visible`.  Next, where are you setting this?  In Page load?

Comment: <td align="right"><asp:LinkButton ID="PDFbutton" runat="server" Visible="True">Preview & Print</asp:LinkButton></td> creates the LinkButton.  PDFbutton.Visible = False is called in the PageLoad.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question to include the full code-behind of your page? What you posted above is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried setting .Visible = false outside the if/then logic?

If that works, then you want to troubleshoot the logic.  Add my first line to what you show above, then change your first line to my second line.

```
Dim hideRpt as Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session("HideReports")) 
If Not hideRpt Then
```

Now put a breakpoint on the "If Not..." line.

If you aren't getting what you expect, add another line to get a string for the session value, to make sure it really should convert to a bool.

Basic troubleshooting, man, break it down into smaller parts.  Sometimes I'll start a fresh windows app just to have a blank slate on which to work out details.

Comment: I've tried that.  I have tried setting the .Visible to true outside of any validation with zero success.  Made me doubt that it could be done in that manner which is why I asked here.

Comment: Visible="True" is not needed in your markup.  That shouldn't change anything, but no harm in trying.  There is no reason I know of that you couldn't set this control to .Visible = False in your PageLoad event.  But, I have to agree with other commenters at this point...would have to see more complete version of code to have a chance to see the problem.

Comment: Actually, .Visible *defaults* to true...the LinkButton should display unless you explicitly set it to .Visible = false.  I did run a quick test, and setting .Visible=false in Page_Load does hide the button.  I would also say that is a better way to write your code...test for the logic that says you want to hide the button, not the logic that says you want to show it.